# Python: Iterating lists with different amount of dimensions, is there a generic way?

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, multidimensional-array

```
# 2x3 dimensional list
multidim_list = [ 
                  [1,2,3],
                  [4,5,6],    
                ]
# 2x3x2 dimensional list
multidim_list2 = [ 
                   [ 
                     [1,2,3],
                     [4,5,6],  
                   ],
                   [ 
                     [7,8,9],
                     [10,11,12],  
                   ]
                 ]

def multiply_list(list):
    ...
```

I would like to implement a function, that would multiply all elements in list by two. However my problem is that lists can have different amount of dimensions.

Is there a general way to loop/iterate multidimensional list and for example multiply each value by two?

EDIT1:
  Thanks for the fast answers.
  For this case, I don't want to use numpy.
  The recursion seems good, and it doesn't even need to make copy of the list, which could be quite large actually.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recursion is your friend:

```
from collections import MutableSequence
def multiply(list_):
    for index, item in enumerate(list_):
        if isinstance(item, MutableSequence):
            multiply(item)
        else:
            list_[index] *= 2
```

You could just do `isinstance(item, list)` instead of `isinstance(item, MutableSequence)`, but the latter way is more futureproof and generic. See [the glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-abstract-base-class) for a short explanation.

Comment: This is what I wanted. It has been long since I previously used recursion, have almost forgotten it. And I didn't want to use numpy for this case.

Comment: "… it is also the way such checks are done in the python libraries."  Just out of curiosity – what Python libraries do you have in mind here?

Comment: @Sven Busted. Searching the "batteries" I've found no such check. Closest I've come is that shutil uses `isinstance(function, collections.Callable)`. There's tons of `isinstance(x, list)` checks though. I _thougth_ that wherever a built-in function or class needed to check the type of its args (e.g. is it a list or a dict) it would do this by using the ABCs in `collections`, so that users might substitute the `list` object with a `MutableSequence` subclass and still have it work. Honestly, I thought this was a big reason why they introduced the ABCs in the first place. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can make use of numpy:

```
import numpy as np

arr_1 = np.array(multidim_list)
arr_2 = np.array(multidim_list2)
```

Result:

```
>>> arr_1*2
array([[ 2,  4,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12]])
>>> arr_2*2
array([[[ 2,  4,  6],
        [ 8, 10, 12]],

       [[14, 16, 18],
        [20, 22, 24]]])
```

Answer (score 3):

[numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays do that out of the box.